# Java, Simplified check if int array contains int

Tags: java, arrays, int, contains

Basically my mate has been saying that I could make my code shorter by using a different way of checking if an int array contains an int, although he won't tell me what it is :P.

Current:

```
public boolean contains(final int[] array, final int key) {
    for (final int i : array) {
        if (i == key) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Have also tried this, although it always returns false for some reason.

```
public boolean contains(final int[] array, final int key) {
    return Arrays.asList(array).contains(key);
}
```

Could anyone help me out?

Thank you.

Comment: Your Arrays.asList(...) call takes a vararg, that is it will wrap the arbitrary number of arguments you might pass into that in a List. In your case, you're getting a list of arrays with a single element, and this list obviously does not contain the int.

Comment: Your comment meaning what now?

Comment: check `Hashset` based retrial mechanism answer. It is the fastest way.

Comment: I don't see any point at making your original code shorter since your argument is a primitive array and your code is very clear and straightfoward. `ArrayList` implementation is doing the same.

Comment: I would not make your code shorter. (1) arraylist does the same thing you did. (2) - more important stuff is that the shorten code using Arrays.asList creates new object, which could be problem within some performance critical code. The first code snippet is best thing you can do.

Comment: The iterative solution is nice. Of course you can use a Hashtable to optimize the speed of the lookup, but that means to convert the initial array into a hashtable, which is also an iterative process. Anyway, I would add a "break" statement when the item is found, because when it is found, you don't need to iterate to the end of the array

Comment: Hi, even if the JDK8 version is smaller the speed depenends on the list size. For example if your list contain less than 10 elements the simple array loop could be much faster because integer call are fast an there is no calling overhead like in the jdk8 solution. For really large set you sould use an "Set<>" but it is only faster if you reuse it.

Comment: Your Current is the best way if your using Java 7, int, with no 3rd Party libraries.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It's because `Arrays.asList(array)` returns `List<int[]>`. The `array` argument is treated as one value you want to wrap (you get a list of arrays of ints), not as vararg.

Note that it *does* work with object types (not primitives):

```
public boolean contains(final String[] array, final String key) {
    return Arrays.asList(array).contains(key);
}
```

or even:

```
public <T>  boolean contains(final T[] array, final T key) {
    return Arrays.asList(array).contains(key);
}
```

But you cannot have `List<int>` and autoboxing is not working here.

Comment: Why autoboxing does not work, is it because it is declared as final?

Answer (score 80):

You could simply use [`ArrayUtils.contains`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#contains(int%5B%5D,%20int)) from Apache Commons Lang library.

```
public boolean contains(final int[] array, final int key) {     
    return ArrayUtils.contains(array, key);
}
```

Comment: As long as you are using ArrayUtils, is there any reason not to use [ArrayUtils.contains](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#contains(int[],%20int))

Comment: No reason whatsoever :)

Comment: It's worth noting that `ArrayUtils.contains()` is part of `Apache Commons Lang` library. Even though that's a great lib, it is probably still not a good idea to add external dependency just to check if array contains an element :D

Comment: ArrayUtils is a thing of past. Java 8+ and Guava have pretty amazing goodies!!

Answer (score 71):

Here is Java 8 solution

```
public static boolean contains(final int[] arr, final int key) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr).anyMatch(i -> i == key);
}
```

Comment: Note that this call requires API level 24

Answer (score 21):

A different way:

```
public boolean contains(final int[] array, final int key) {  
     Arrays.sort(array);  
     return Arrays.binarySearch(array, key) >= 0;  
}
```

This modifies the passed-in array. You would have the option to copy the array and work on the original array i.e. `int[] sorted = array.clone();`
But this is just an example of short code. The runtime is `O(NlogN)` while your way is `O(N)`

Comment: I think I'd be surprised if a `contains` method modified my array.

Comment: @ZongLi:This is just an example for the OP.Updated OP if we are nitpicking

Comment: From javadoc of binarySearch(): "the return value will be >= 0 if and only if the key is found." so Arrays.binarySearch(array,key)>=0 should be returned!

Comment: Supplement: The return value of binarySearch() is (-(insertion point) - 1) if key is not contained which may likely be a value other than -1.

Comment: This can't be `-1` if it is intending to be true. "The insertion point is defined as the point at which the key would be inserted into the list: the index of the first element greater than the key, or list.size() if all elements in the list are less than the specified key.". Need to say `>= 0`.

Comment: Sorting and binary-searching is more "expensive" than full scan. (Besides the fact that array would be modified)

Answer (score 21):

Guava offers additional methods for primitive types. Among them a contains method which takes the same arguments as yours.

```
public boolean contains(final int[] array, final int key) {
    return Ints.contains(array, key);
}
```

You might as well statically import the guava version.

See [Guava Primitives Explained](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/PrimitivesExplained)

Answer (score 19):

I know it's super late, but try `Integer[]` instead of `int[]`.

Answer (score 3):

1.one-off uses

```
List<T> list=Arrays.asList(...)
list.contains(...)
```

2.use HashSet for performance consideration if you use more than once.

```
Set <T>set =new HashSet<T>(Arrays.asList(...));
set.contains(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your primitive int array into an arraylist of Integers using below Java 8 code,

```
List<Integer> arrayElementsList = Arrays.stream(yourArray).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And then use `contains()` method to check if the list contains a particular element,

```
boolean containsElement = arrayElementsList.contains(key);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `java.util.Arrays` class to transform the array `T[?]` in a `List<T>` object with methods like `contains`:

```
Arrays.asList(int[] array).contains(int key);
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 9+

```java
public boolean contains(final int[] array, final int key) {
    return List.of(array).contains(key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**this worked in java 8**

```
public static boolean contains(final int[] array, final int key)
{
return Arrays.stream(array).anyMatch(n->n==key);
}
```

Comment: It should immediately return on first match, instead this will still scan all the items in array, even if it did find the match. (Consider an array of trilion items)

Comment: You are right try this           public static boolean contains(final int[] array, final int key)
    {
    return Arrays.stream(array).anyMatch(n->n==key);
    }

Comment: Java 8 stream anyMatch is a [short-circuit operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) and will not scan all items in the array.

Comment: @LordParsley Above code's goal is check element in array ,not scan all element of array.

Comment: Sorry, I see the answer was edited. I was just reiterating it was correct as it will not need to scan all if it finds one part way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void arrayContains(){
    int myArray[]={2,2,5,4,8};

    int length=myArray.length;

    int toFind = 5;
    boolean found = false;

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if(myArray[i]==toFind) {
            found=true;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(myArray.length);
    System.out.println(found); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void solutions() {
    int[] A = { 1, 5, 10, 20, 40, 80 };
    int[] B = { 6, 7, 20, 80, 100 };
    int[] C = { 3, 4, 15, 20, 30, 70, 80, 120 };

    List<Integer> aList = Arrays.stream(A).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

    List<Integer> cList = Arrays.stream(C).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    String s = "";
    for (Integer a : C) {
        if (aList.contains(a) && cList.contains(a)) {
            s = s.concat(String.valueOf(a)).concat("->");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Depending on how large your array of int will be, you will get much better performance if you use collections and `.contains` rather than iterating over the array one element at a time:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import java.util.HashSet;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class IntLookupTest {

int numberOfInts = 500000;
int toFind = 200000;
int[] array;

HashSet<Integer> intSet;

@Before
public void initializeArrayAndSet() {
    array = new int[numberOfInts];
    intSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfInts; i++) {
        array[i] = i;
        intSet.add(i);
    }
}

@Test
public void lookupUsingCollections() {
    assertTrue(intSet.contains(toFind));
}

@Test
public void iterateArray() {
    assertTrue(contains(array, toFind));

}

public boolean contains(final int[] array, final int key) {
    for (final int i : array) {
        if (i == key) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score -6):

Try `Integer.parseInt()` to do this.....

```
public boolean chkInt(final int[] array){
    int key = false;

    for (Integer i : array){


          try{

                   Integer.parseInt(i);
                   key = true;
                   return key;

             }catch(NumberFormatException ex){

                   key = false;

                   return key;

              }


     }
}
```