# How Arrays.asList(int[]) can return List<int[]>?

Tags: java

While doing simple program I noticed this issue.

```
int[] example = new int[10];
List<Integer> exampleList = Arrays.asList(example);// Compilation error here
```

Compilation error is returned as `cannot convert from List<int[]> to List<Integer>`. But `List<int>` is not permitted in java so why this kind of compilation error?

I am not questioning about autoboxing here I just wondered how `Arrays.asList` can return `List<int[]>`.

asList implementation is

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) {
return new ArrayList<T>(a);
}
```

So it is treating int[] as T that is why this is happening.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12020391/605744

Comment: You are wondering about how `Arrays.asList` can return a `List<int>` but the error message you are getting is clearly saying you `List<int[]>` instead of `List<int>`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no automatic autoboxing done of the underlying ints in `Arrays.asList`.

- `int[]` is actually an object, not a primitive.
- Here `Arrays.asList(example)` returns `List<int[]>`. `List<int>` is indeed invalid syntax.
- You could use:

  List<Integer> exampleList = Arrays.asList(ArrayUtils.toObject(array));

  using Apache Commons `ArrayUtils`.

Answer (score 2):

`Arrays.asList(...)` works perfectly to transform an array of objects into a list of those objects.

Also, `Arrays.asList(...)` is defined in Java 5 with a varag construct, or, in order words, it can accept an undefined number of parameters in which case it will consider all of those parameters as members of an array and then return a `List` instance containing those elements.

```
List<Object> objList = Arrays.asList(obj1, obj2, obj3);
```

That means you can create a list with a single element:

```
List<Object> objList = Arrays.asList(obj1);
```

Since `List<int>` is not permitted in Java, when you use a `int[]` array as parameter for `Arrays.asList` it will consider it as the single element of a list instead of an array of `int`. That's because arrays are objects by themselves in Java while an `int` (and any other primitive) is not.

So, when converting an array of primitives, `Arrays.asList` will try to return a list of primitive arrays:

```
List<int[]> intArrayList = Arrays.asList(new int[]{ 1, 2, 3 });
```

Answer (score 2):

The signature `<T> List<T> asList(T... os)` involves a generic type `T`. The extent of generic types covers only reference types (including array types), but not primitive types. Therefore in an invocation `Arrays.asList(ints)` with `int[] ints` the `T` can only be resolved to `int[]`.

On a higher level, the purpose of `Arrays.asList` is to provide a **list view** of your array. That means that the array stays untouched and its elements are made available through an object implementing `List`. However, `List`s can only contain objects and your array contains primitive `int`s. That makes the array uneligible for being exposed through a `List` interface.

Anyway, if you are looking for an elegant syntax to create a list of `Integers`, write `Arrays.asList(1,2,3)`.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are objects in java, not primitive types. Note that it says `List<int[]>` (list of int-arrays), not `List<int>`.