# Arrays.asList(arrayname).contains(int) doesnt work

Tags: java

```
int[] AllCards = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

if(Arrays.asList(AllCards).contains(1))
    System.out.println("yes");
else {
    System.out.println("no");
}
```

I have this code and it just keeps printing `no` instead of `yes`. What is wrong?

Comment: `Arrays.asList(AllCards)` returns a `List<int[]>`, hence it can´t find a single value in the `List`. The reason behind it can be read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020886/how-arrays-aslistint-can-return-listint)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Integer[] AllCards = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

if(Arrays.asList(AllCards).contains(1))
    System.out.println("yes");
else {
    System.out.println("no");
}
```

to understand why check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1467940/4088809

Comment: thank you! how can i see if a array contains that number twice?

Comment: if(Collections.frequency(Arrays.asList(AllCards), 1) == 2) ==> This will check if the number 1 is present twice ( of course you need to replace 1 with the number you are looking for.)

Answer (score 1):

Since `AllCards` is an `int` array the call `Arrays.asList(AllCards)` returns a List with a single element, namely `AllCards`.

If you don't want to change `AllCards` to an `Integer` array you can write the following to test if it contains 1:

```
boolean containsOne = Arrays.stream(AllCards).anyMatch(n -> n == 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that `1` is autoboxed as an `Integer` not an `int`.

Change declaration to `Integer[]`

Answer (score 0):

Change `int` to `Integer` :

```
Integer[] AllCards = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

if(Arrays.asList(AllCards).contains(1))
    System.out.println("yes");
else {
    System.out.println("no");
}
```

**In Java,** the 'int' type is a primitive , whereas the 'Integer' type is an object.

It means, that if you want to transform an `array` to a `List` type, you need objects, because you can't save primitive types into a List.