# Checking for an integer in array

Tags: java, arrays, random

I have an exercise to do in college, part of which consists of creating a pack of cards which must then be shuffled. I have the cards in an array (not shuffled) and want to shuffle them and push them onto a home made Stack, from which I can pop the cards off to deal them.

My problem is that I want to check that the random number I generate (and which represents one of the cards in the array) is not already in the Stack. From reading on this forum I have come up with the code below which, it seems to me should work. On debugging though I notice duplicates.

As per my comment below we can't use the Collections framework (edit)

```
private Stack<Card> deck;//to hold cards
private Card[] protoDeck;//to hold cards before shuffling
private Random randomer;

private int cardsDealt;//how many cards used. Used for other methods
private static final int TOTALCARDS = 52;//sets limit of deck for all decks

public void shuffle(){//remove cards from deck and put back in random order
    randomer = new Random();
    int[] temp = new int[TOTALCARDS];//to keep track of random numbers
    int rand = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < temp.length ; i++) {
        do {//keep creating randoms if 
            rand = randomer.nextInt(TOTALCARDS);
            deck.push(protoDeck[rand]);//puts the Card onto the Deck in a random position
            temp[i] = rand;
        } while (!(Arrays.asList(temp).contains(rand)));//check if the number already used  
    }
}
```

---

@PeterLawrey I have tweaked the code slightly as follows as I only need to shuffle full decks and it works a treat, I will pop cards off the Stack to deal

---

```
public void shuffle() {
    randomer = new Random();
    for(int i = 0; i < TOTALCARDS; i++) {
        // pick a random card from the rest of the deck
        int j = randomer.nextInt(protoDeck.length - i) + i;
        // swap cards
        Card tmp = protoDeck[i];
        protoDeck[i] = protoDeck[j];
        protoDeck[j] = tmp;
        deck.push(protoDeck[i]);
    }

}
```

Thanks to Peter and all the other contributors. M.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said that we can't use the Colections framework.

Comment: To avoid duplicates, check `deck.contains()`before pushing; that should show if the card is already in the shuffled desk.

Comment: Without using Collections.shuffle, you can use the same code.  You can optimise the code to pick N random cards, rather than shuffling the whole deck.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951547/java-array-finding-duplicates

Comment: +1 for effort and showing us code

Comment: @PeterLawrey The trouble is the Card[] protoDeck has to contain 4 * Ace, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, Jack, Queen, King for the four suits, the suits aren't important for this exercise but we must have 4 of each card.

Comment: "we must have 4 of each card" see my answer. It will allow you to select 4 random and unique cards.

Comment: Only barely on topic but interesting read about card shuffling algorithms: http://www.cigital.com/papers/download/developer_gambling.php

Comment: @Trengot I might even look at that after I have finished this ##### assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with

```
private final Card[] deck;//to hold cards before shuffling
private final Random rand = new Random();
```

You can do

```
public void shuffle() {
    // no need the shuffle the last card.
    shuffle(deck.length - 1);
}

// will leave the first N card random without duplicates.
public void shuffle(int numberOfCards) {
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfCards; i++) {
        // pick a random card from the rest of the deck
        int j = rand.nextInt(protoDeck.length - i) + i;
        // swap cards
        Card tmp = deck[i];
        deck[i] = deck[j];
        deck[j] = tmp;
    }
}
```

The cost is O(N) where N is the number of random cards.

---

Imagine you have a small Deck like

```
AS AC AD AH 2S 2C 2D 2H
```

and you need to pick a random first card, you select one from the deck and swap that card. Say nextInt() is 5 => 2C

```
2C | AC AD AH 2S AS 2D 2H
```

The desk is made up of cards randomly selected + not selected.  You have no duplicates because the same cards get moved around.  The next random card is say 2H which is swapped with AC

```
2C 2H | AD AH 2S AS 2D AC
```

Finally AD happens to be selected.

```
2C 2H AD | AH 2S AS 2D AC
```

This gives you three random cards and the rest.  The same array can be use again as starting with a sorted or random deck doesn't make the result any more or less random.

---

In reply to the answer [Why does this simple shuffle algorithm produce biased results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859253/why-does-this-simple-shuffle-algorithm-produce-biased-results-what-is-a-simple) if there is 123, the possible outcomes are

```
123
 +- 123          - swap 1 and 1 (these are positions, not numbers)
 |   +- 123      - swap 2 and 2
 |   +- 132      - swap 2 and 3
 +- 213          - swap 1 and 2
 |   +- 213      - swap 2 and 2
 |   +- 231      - swap 2 and 3
 +- 321          - swap 1 and 3
     +- 321      - swap 2 and 2
     +- 312      - swap 2 and 3
```

As you can see there is only 6 possible outcomes, all equally likely.

Comment: +1 for a solution that doesn't use additional memory ;)

Comment: @Peter Lawrey:Sorry, but I don't think this will work.
  int j = rand.nextInt(protoDeck.length - i) + i;
this line can give you 1 for every run because the parameter for nextInt is just an upper limit so the numbers won't be unique.

Comment: @user2424380 The number doesn't need to be.  Imagine you are selecting a random card from a deck without replacing it.  If you select another card, it won't be a duplicate because you are not selecting from a card you have already selected.  Imagine your just pick the first card each time and the nextInt() is zero every time.  You will pick the 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ... card. It is still unique.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thanks, I will have a look at this, as a matter of interest why do you have `shuffle()` and `shuffle(int numberOfCards)`? The number of cards will always be 52, that's why I have TOTALCARDS set to 52

Comment: @mobeirn When you deal some cards, you often deal N random cards at a time, not always all 52.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I have tweaked the code slightly as follows as I only need to shuffle full decks and it works a treat, I will pop cards off the Stack to deal. `public void shuffle() {
  randomer = new Random();
     for(int i = 0; i < TOTALCARDS; i++) {
         // pick a random card from the rest of the deck
         int j = randomer.nextInt(protoDeck.length - i) + i;
         // swap cards
         Card tmp = protoDeck[i];
         protoDeck[i] = protoDeck[j];
         protoDeck[j] = tmp;
         deck.push(protoDeck[i]);
     }
     
 }`

Comment: @mobeirn That should work.  Don't forget to clear() the stack if you need to reshuffle e.g. on a black jack.

Comment: @PeterLawrey:
Sorry, my mistake, it works. Howewer I'm still not a big fan of this kind of shuffling, see here why:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859253/why-does-this-simple-shuffle-algorithm-produce-biased-results-what-is-a-simple

Comment: @user2424380 As long as the bias is towards the Casino, I'm sure they won't mind. I have already told (and demonstrated) to my kids why they should NEVER play Blackjack for money...

Comment: @user2424380 I don't use that approach. Note: I swap with an ever decreasing number of cards to choose from.

Comment: @user2424380 I have used the answer in the link you gave to explore all the possible outcomes for 1 2 3

Comment: @PeterLawrey: you got me with that +i... I've checked the probabilty tree and you're right. +1 :)

Comment: @user2424380 generating random numbers with an ever smaller range is also a micro-optimisation.

Answer (score 1):

Actually Stack extends Vector. So you can use contains method to check that already element is there or not.

Comment: It is a home made Stack so I was hoping not to have to create all the methods from scratch. Good point though, I'll have a look at making the contains() method in my home made one.

Answer (score 1):

The original problem is that `Arrays.asList(temp)` does not create a `List<Integer>` but a `List<int[]>`.

Hence `Arrays.asList(temp).contains(rand)` returns always `false`.

If you used the wrapper class `Integer` (`Integer[] temp = new Integer[TOTALCARDS];`), it would work but your approach is very inefficient, as you will have to generate a "random" number in a set that would reduce at each iteration.

One way would be to create an array containing the position 0 to 51, shuffle it and then iterate through it to push the cards in the deck.

```
public void shuffle(){//remove cards from deck and put back in random order
    int[] temp = new int[TOTALCARDS];//to keep track of random numbers
    for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){
        temp[i] = i;
    }

    //shuffle the array

    for (int i = 0; i < temp.length ; i++) {
        deck.push(protoDeck[temp[i]]);             
    }
}
```

This approach runs in O(n) time.

Comment: Instead of shuffling the array or `int[]`, why not just shuffle the `Card[]`?

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yes, if he doesn't want to keep a "sorted" array of Cards, your option is definitely the best.

Comment: @PeterLawrey so that the original Card[] protoDeck contains the 4 batches of 13 cards in random order? That would remove a step alright and I could just create a new deck each time I need to shuffle. As it is for Blackjack I only need to shuffle if all the cards have been exhausted or there is a Blackjack. I'll definitely try this and get back to you.

Comment: @ZouZou Thanks, that makes sense. This seems to work though `List<Card> tempCards = Arrays.asList(protoDeck);`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I got it wrong, but I think your concept is bad.

1. generate random number
2. put it in the new deck
3. check if it is already there

It sounds to me like a wrong order. On the other hand using a Set is always working if you want unique elements.

Answer (score -1):

As @[ZouZou](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23292304/2591612) states, `Arrays.asList(temp)` returns a `List<int[]>`. You may be doing this because of the confusion brought on by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13789151/2591612) (which wrong by the way). This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12020425/2591612) shows a way you can do it using binary searching:

```
public boolean contains(final int[] array, final int key) 
{  
     Arrays.sort(array);  
     return Arrays.binarySearch(array, key) >= 0;  
}
```

This modifies the passed-in array. You would have the option to copy the array and work on the original array i.e. `int[] sorted = array.clone();` But this is just an example of short code. The runtime is `O(NlogN)`.

Per the Java documentation, binarySearch will return one of the following (I highlighted the important points):

the index of the search key, if it is contained in the list; otherwise, **(-(insertion point) - 1)**. The **insertion point** is defined as the point at which the key would be inserted into the list: **the index of the first element greater than the key, or list.size() if all elements in the list are less than the specified key**. Note that this guarantees that the return value will be >= 0 if and only if the key is found.

Comment: If this method is planning to return true if the element is in the array you have to do `return Arrays.binarySearch(array, key) >= 0;`. As the doc states _"index of the search key, if it is contained in the array; otherwise, (-(insertion point) - 1). The insertion point is defined as the point at which the key would be inserted into the array"_

Comment: @ZouZou: Ah you are right, let me edit. I read the docs again