# Find an integer in an Array in a short manner in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, hashmap, instantiation

I already tried this post:
[Java, Simplified check if int array contains int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020361/java-simplified-check-if-int-array-contains-int)

and tried this

```
int[] temp = {3,9,15,21,27,33,39};
HashSet<Integer> otherBy3 = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(temp));
```

based on the post i saw on the above link instructing me to do this:

```
HashSet<Integer> set= new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(intArray));
set.contains(intValue)
```

but I keep getting this error

```
cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor HashSet(java.util.List<int[]>)
location: class java.util.HashSet<java.lang.Integer> HashSet<Integer> otherBy3 = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(temp));
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The first answer on that link points out what happens when `int[]` to `Arrays.asList` (and why it doesn't do what you want)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
int[] temp = ...
```

to

```
Integer[] temp = ...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Integer[] temp = {3,9,15,21,27,33,39};
HashSet<Integer> set= new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(temp));
System.out.println(set.contains(3));
```

Answer (score 1):

Change **int** to **Integer** because you are declaring the **List** with generic as **Integer**

```
Integer[] temp = new Integer[] { 3, 9, 15, 21, 27, 33, 39 };
HashSet<Integer> otherBy3 = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(temp));
otherBy3.contains(13);
```

Answer (score 1):

Asusming the real problem ou're asking about is "how to find an integer in an int[] array", why not just use [Arrays.html#binarySearch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28int%5B%5D,%20int%29). It's a one-liner, very quick O( log n) and is the common way of doing it. The only pre-req is that your list is sorted and yours appears to be (isn't it?).

```
int[] temp = {3,9,15,21,27,33,39};
int k = 28;    //Not present in temp
if (Arrays.binarySearch(temp, k) > 0) {
    //key found
}
else {
    //key not found - returns -5 (negative indicating not found)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it somewhat disturbing that constructing several temporary objects is regarded "shorter" than a simple freaking loop:

```
 int[] temp = {3,9,15,21,27,33,39};
 boolean found = false;
 for (int i=0; i<temp.length && !found; ++i) {
     found = valueToFind == temp[i];         
 }
```

Its about the same amount of code as the high overhead approaches.

Comment: What about a [binary search](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=binarySearch) instead? Takes at most log n. You even get a free impl in `Arrays#binarySearch`.

Comment: That requires sorting. Sorting is O(N log N) (at best) vs a plain O(N) for the simple loop. The question is mainly about "short" (in amount of code lines, I assume), and I just put this answer to point out that "just doing it" is about as long as going through lengths to do it as a byproduct of something else. If the aim would be on performance, you'd need a lot more context to select the best method.

Comment: OK. The list is sorted in the question but perhaps that's just incidental.