# How to check whether number is present in integer or not

Tags: java

I have a number array.

E.g.

```
76543,65334,776958,8978,2436,232789
```

How can I check if the integers contain `7`, `8` and `9`, no matter the order?

E.g. `776958, 8978` and `232789` contain `7`, `8` and `9`, while `76543` only contains `7`

Comment: `weather` is the wrong word in context and place you put it in. Solution for your problem convert to string and check with `contains` method

Comment: Do you mean the digits "7", "8" and "9" present in "8978" or?

Comment: @procrastinator "7","8"," 9"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java, Simplified check if int array contains int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020361/java-simplified-check-if-int-array-contains-int)

Comment: @Tom that suggested answer doesn't match the requirements. it checks if the array contains e.g. `7` as single value and not if any value inside the array contains all the integer

Comment: @XtremeBaumer That suggested question does what OP asks in his question. If he fails to explain what he ___actually___ needs in it, then it isn't my problem.

Comment: @Tom he actually explains it. It is not his problem if you can't read the question properly (which **is your** problem)

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I guess you're right. That 4 others also thought this question unclear and that your answer is based on OPs comments doesn't matter in this case here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int[] ints = new int[] { 76543, 65334, 776958, 8978, 2436, 232789 };
for (int i : ints) {
    boolean containsAllThree = false;
    if (String.valueOf(i).contains("7") && String.valueOf(i).contains("8") && String.valueOf(i).contains("9"))
        containsAllThree = true;
    System.out.println(containsAllThree);
}
```

since you need don't need `789` but `7`, `8` and `9` to be contained you have to perform 3 checks (i merged it into the `IF` condition)

Answer (score 0):

You must convert this number to String and them compare is exist this subString. I think if you do this you can resolve.

```
boolean present = false;
int[] arr = {12123,432552,4534534};
for(int num : arr){
  String aux = Integer.toString(num);
  if(aux.contains("789"))
    present = true;
}
```

Comment: `Int` doesn't exist. also it doesn't satisfy the requirements

Comment: Is a little code error, now i change and is fix it.

Comment: still your code doesn't meet the requirements. read the question carefully as well as the comments

Comment: I will not fighting with you dude , if you prefer your solution i don't care but my solution, search if the **789** is in the items of a int array, that is the question. Bye man!

Comment: `E.g. 776958, 8978 and 232789 contain 798.` your code will only work on `232789` but not the other two examples

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use JAVA8, you can use a stream. Map it to a String, then check if that String contains the numbers:

```
int[] arr = new int[] {1,2,3897};
System.out.println(Arrays.stream(arr)
                  .mapToObj(i -> String.valueOf(i))
                  .anyMatch(s -> s.contains("7") && s.contains("8") && s.contains("9")));
```

Depending on your exact needs, you could also use the stream to filter out the numbers that contain your numbers (or those that don't) with the `.filter()` method of the Stream.

```
int[] arr = new int[] {1,2,3897};
List list = Arrays.stream(arr)
            .filter(i -> String.valueOf(i).contains("7")  && String.valueOf(i).contains("8") && String.valueOf(i).contains("9"))
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(list);
```